# Android(JAVA) P2P WiFi Direct

Tags: multipeer-connectivity, wifip2p, peer

In **P2P** using **Wifi direct** I can able to listed and connected the client devices to server device, but able to transfer data from server to only one client at a time. **My doubt is!!!** - Is it possible to transfer data from server to multiple clients at a time? in **P2P Wifi direct**. *Thanks in advance...*

Answer (score 0):

UDP broadcast is possible within a WiFi Direct group. Make sure you add the permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
```